# Source control architectecture for game

Tags: git, version-control, branch, versioning

I know about the technicalities of creating branches (I'm using git), merging and so on.

I'm developing a game whose direction isn't known, and I want to keep track of both bigger and smaller changes. For example, program versioning can use the notation `XX.YY.ZZ` where XX is a major version, `YY` is a minor version and `ZZ` is a bugfix.

So do I make a commit for each bugfix, and branches for major and minor versions?
Is there a way to make a sub-branch of a branch?

What is the usual method for handling this?

Comment: The usual method is creating bugfix branch and then merging into the main branch. So what's the problem for you to applying this method for your source code?

Answer (score 0):

No.
You commit every time... you just create a branch to a new bug fix or function
The version of your game you control with [TAGS](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

To each fix you create a new branch, do what you need, commit aways you feel necessary and when you finish the fix you merge this branch to master, and when you publish something you create a tag

See [feature branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) in this article